# what are URL options?

Tags: ios, swift, communication

The current, official documentation for `open(_:options:completionHandler:)`
 UIApplication instance method (src: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open )

Says:

> **options**
>
> A dictionary of options to use when opening the URL. For a
>   list of possible keys to include in this dictionary, see *URL Options*.

However, there is no section on *URL options*. Nor does any page reasonably attributable to that purpose come up when searching help.

What are URL options? 
What may the values be? 
Are there any standards for encrypting the data in these so that only the intended recipient can read them?

Comment: The url options are listed @ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/openurloptionskey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently only one option you can include: [`universalLinksOnly`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/openexternalurloptionskey/1648680-universallinksonly). [Universal links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) are URLs that apps signed up to handle, for example: the YouTube app can sign up to open links to the `youtube.com` domain.

If you include `universalLinksOnly` option, the URL will only open if there's an app configured to open it. Returning to our example: to open a YouTube video, you must have the YouTube app installed.